# Monaco Editor not displaying correctly after NPM Prod

Tags: laravel, vue.js, monaco-editor

Have a very strange issue with Monaco Editor. When developing, and running NPM RUN WATCH, editor displays perfectly in browser. After running NPM RUN PROD, the view breaks. See below. I have tried everything to resolve this, webpack changes, CSS changes, Moved out of Patternfly Code Block elements.
The only error I get after NPM RUN PROD in the console is
'Element already has context attribute: pf-c-code-editor__code-pre'
Ignoring the actual attribute, I get the same error when attribute is present. I think this is a red herring though.
Running VUE3, Laravel, latest Monaco. Sample editor code below
See any tips or advice and what to do next?

[image]

[image]

```
        const codeEditorDiv = document.getElementById('pf-c-code-editor__code-pre');
        meditor = monaco.editor.create(codeEditorDiv, {
            value: meditorValue.value,
            language: language.value || 'javascript',
            lineNumbers: lineNumbers.value,
            roundedSelection: false,
            readOnly: false,
            theme: darkmode.value,
            scrollBeyondLastLine: true,
            wordWrap: 'on',
            wrappingStrategy: 'advanced',
            automaticLayout: true,
            minimap: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
```

Updated Screenshots, before (NPM RUN DEV) and after (NPM RUN PROD)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a CSS issue? Checked your devtools?

Comment: Your right, it is a CSS issue. More screenshots above. First is normal render, second is rendered afer NPM RUN PROD. You will see that the 'monaco-editor' div is rendered twice. The bottom one has the main content. You will also see that there is a duplicate class (generated by monaco) on the 'pf-c-code-editor__code-pre'.
Very strange!

Comment: Compare it to `dev` build to be sure.